# SQL 'LIKE' clause with apostrophe

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

If im trying to search for 'RYAN'S TEAM' in sql it doesnt like the fact that i have an apostrophe ' in RYAN'S and detects that as the end of the LIKE statement.

```
    [Team] LIKE '%RYAN'S TEAM%'
```

It recognises the whole next line as red in sql server. Is there anyway around this as RYAN'S TEAM is the way it is stored in the database.

Comment: You can escape it with another quote. Like this: `[Team] LIKE '%RYAN''S TEAM%'`

Comment: [sql-server] or [my-sql]? please fix your tags.

Comment: this must have a duplicate.... let me find it for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
 [Team] LIKE '%RYAN''S TEAM%'
```

You just have to double the quote chars.